# Vaadin flow apps not working with spring boot 2.6.0

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin21

I've updated a Vaadin 21/Spring Boot 2.5.7 application to Spring Boot 2.6.0 and are experiencing issues with the rendering. It appears that the resources are not being made available for the frontend. I have confirmed that they are packaged into the war.

There are no errors logged but images from resources are not being shown in the ui.

Looking at the release notes for 2.6.0 it appears that they have made changes to how resources are being included/served.

Can anyone else confirm this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a fix is already on the way https://github.com/vaadin/spring/pull/944